# How the instance of a class can pass itself by a function?

Tags: function, class, inheritance, constructor, this

How can I pass the "current class" throw a function(constructor) of another class by reference?

In this example I want to pass the "current" class A to the class C (with C and B polymorphic), the class C must be able to use the function A::getValue() and return the correct value.

Can I do it using using **this** ( bc = new C(??this??); )?

Is the constructor C(A aTemp) correct ? The goal is to pass the class via reference...

main.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
#include "C.h"
int main()
{
  A * cA = new A();
  std::cout << "main: "<<  std::endl;
  cA->aRun();
  return 0;
}
```

A.h

```
#ifndef A_h
#define A_h
#include "B.h"
#include "C.h"
class A{
public:
int iMain = 2;
void aRun(){B *bc; bc = new C(??this??);}
void setValue(int temp){iMain = temp;};
int getValue(){return iMain;};
};
#endif
```

B.h

```
#ifndef B_h
#define B_h
#include "A.h"
class B{
 public:
 B(){};
 ~B(){};
};
#endif
```

C.cpp

```
#include "C.h"
void C::cRun(){
    std::cout << "cRun: " << A->getValue() << std::endl;
    }
```

C.h

```
#ifndef C_h
#define C_h
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "C.h"
#include "A.h"
class C:  public B{
 public:
 A *a;
 C(??A aTemp??){ a = aTemp};
 void cRun();
};
#endif
```

Comment: A question like this *needs* a tag designating the relevant language, which in this case appears to be C++.  I'd add it for you, if you did not already have the maximum number, but as it is, I defer to you to choose which of the existing tags to remove.  FWIW, however, I don't think *any* of the current tags are very helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by "pass ... by a function"? What do you mean when you talk about passing classes? Classes aren't values; you can't "pass" them.

Comment: Note, too, that you say you want to pass a ***class***, but you appear to be trying to pass an ***instance***, which would make a lot more sense.  A class would be much more appropriate as a template parameter than as a method parameter.

Comment: Yes, the **instance** of the **class** is the correct terminology